# jsPerf of Object setter/getters has odd performance with defineProperty

Tags: javascript, performance, object

I modified a [jsPerf comparison](http://jsperf.com/property-access-vs-defineproperty/3) of direct object property access and use of defineProperty.

Both the original test an mine show an unbelievable result with firefox being *very* slow using defineProperty.

This makes me think there's an error in the tests.

Can anyone find the problem?

[image: JS Perf Results]

Comment: Why does it surprise you that different browsers have different performance?

Comment: The extreme simplicity of those tests mean that the runtime may be completely optimizing some of them out of existence.

Comment: 1.7 billion method calls/second?!? That's pretty impressive! Way to go, Mozilla!

Comment: @Nit: not surprised at performance difference .. but the huge difference within firefox on the (nearly invisible) Prop Get/Set numbers when the other 4 are so great.

Comment: @Pointy: that's what several of the Moz team mentioned as well.  I posted this on twitter and got great results from Brendan Eich and folks he forwarded to.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the [new version of the jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/property-access-vs-defineproperty/5) made by mozilla team.  Basically the defineProperty is designed to work on prototypes, not simple objects.  And they're working on the one slow case.

[image]

Thanks FF team!

[image]